# To Stop and Start subscriber on API call

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I've been trying to stop and start subscriber for a `SubscribableChannel` but there seems to be no way to fetch the MessageHandler used to call the `unsubscribe` function.

Using the default autowired bean for MessageHandler gives some default error handler, instead of the channel which I want to unsubscribe from.

What is the way to acheive this? to call `unsubscribe()` and `subscribe()` at run time.

I know of the pause/resume functionality which will be released soon, but can't wait for it and cannot directly use spring-kafka. Hence, trying this as a alternative approach.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/261

Answer (score 0):

Just unsubscribing the channel won't work (even if you could). The kafka consumer has to be paused to suspend delivery or stopped to unsubscribe from the topic. Unsubscribing the channel will cause the container to throw exceptions (no subscribers).

Spring Cloud Stream does not currently support managing the binding lifecycle from your application; you have to shut down the whole application.

Answer (score 0):

seems it's possible next way:

```
@Component
public class StartStopService {
    public void start(int channelIndex) throws IllegalStateException {
        try {
            BindingService bindingService = this.applicationContext
                    .getBean(BindingService.class);

            Map<String, SubscribableChannel> subscribableChannelMap =
                    this.applicationContext.getBeansOfType(SubscribableChannel.class);

            for (Map.Entry<String, SubscribableChannel> subscribableChannel : subscribableChannelMap.entrySet()) {

                final String name = subscribableChannel.getKey();

                if (name.startsWith("product-update-") && name.endsWith("-" + channelIndex)) {
                    bindingService.bindConsumer(subscribableChannel.getValue(), name);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (BeansException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Cannot perform binding, no proper implementation found", e);
        }
    }

    public void stop(int channelIndex) throws IllegalStateException {
        try {
            BindingService bindingService = this.applicationContext
                    .getBean(BindingService.class);

            Map<String, SubscribableChannel> subscribableChannelMap =
                    this.applicationContext.getBeansOfType(SubscribableChannel.class);

            for (Map.Entry<String, SubscribableChannel> subscribableChannel : subscribableChannelMap.entrySet()) {

                final String name = subscribableChannel.getKey();

                if (name.startsWith("product-update-") && name.endsWith("-" + channelIndex)) {
                    bindingService.unbindConsumers(name);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (BeansException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "Cannot perform unbinding, no proper implementation found", e);
        }
    }
}
```